# firefox extensions - detect if button pressed with shift

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, shift

I am trying to write a browser plugin which has two functionalities. I don't need any input, I only need to call a function.

My idea was, that the functionality can by accessed by holding **shift** - or not - when pressing the plugin icon. (**ctrl** would do the job as well)

The problem is, that firefox doesn't give me an event so I can't use `event.shiftKey`. The only thing firefox gives me is the current tab and it doesn't hold that information. Here is what I got so far:

```
// manifest.json
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Link List",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
  }

  "browser_action": {

  }
}


// background.js
function openPage(tab) {
  if(<shift pressed>) {
    funcA();
  } else {
    funcB();
  }
}

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(openPage)
```

Any ideas, what I can put into `<shift pressed>`?

*I am not a native speaker, please correct me if I make grammar / spelling mistakes*

Answer (score -1):

Try using this code:

```
var keys = [];
document.onkeydown = function(e){keys[e.keyCode]=true;};
document.onkeyup = function(e){keys[e.keyCode]=false;};
```

...in your extension. Deploy it as soon as your extension runs on every new page.
In your if statement, you can use `if(keys[16])` for `shift`, or `if(keys[17])` for `ctrl`.

Comment: It seems the code is executed to late. It always calls `funcB()`. You ment, that I should put that code into `background.js` at the top right?

Comment: This is a way to capture keypresses; I don't know where you'd put that in an extension.